# Excel not loading UTF-16LE CSV file properly on MAC OSX

Tags: java, excel, csv, unicode

I am using java to save database data to a CSV file, the problem is certain characters are not being rendered properly in Excel.

specifically the ',' and '<'.

I have a name as such:

```
Angine d’effort sévère (CCS 3/4) stable - B (≤ 10 jours)
```

and as you can see in excel, it is not loaded properly.

[image]

Any ideas? I have tried using other unicode encoding and nothing seems to work. On a windows machine, the file loads properly.... I am out of ideas!